# Stationarity of time series with product of white noise time series

Tags: time-series, stationarity

Is the time series $\{Yt\}$ given by $Y_{t} = Z_{t} - \frac{1}{2}Z_{t-1}Z_{t-2}$

With $Z_{t} \sim{N}(0\,1)$, weakly stationary?

I do not know how to check if the above stated formula is stationary? I am struggling how to interpret the product of the same white noise time series with different lag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $k> 0$ without loss of generality, and assuming white $Z_t$:
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{cov}(Y_t,Y_{t-k})&=\operatorname{cov}(Z_t-\frac{1}{2}Z_{t-1}Z_{t-2},Z_{t-k}-\frac{1}{2}Z_{t-k-1}Z_{t-k-2})\\&=-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{cov}(Z_{t-1}Z_{t-2},Z_{t-k})+\frac{1}{4}\operatorname{cov}(Z_{t-1}Z_{t-2},Z_{t-1-k}Z_{t-2-k})\end{align}$$

Check this expression for $k=1,2$ and greater values. You'll see that the covariance is always $0$. Also, the mean process will be constant.

Comment: should second line be: cov(Zt,,Zt−k)−1/2cov(Zt,Zt−1Zt−2)−1/2cov(Zt−1Zt−2,Zt−k)+1/4cov(Zt−1Zt−2,Zt−1−kZt−2−k)

Comment: Yes, I shortened that a bit because covariance of $Z_t$ with any of the past values will be $0$